# IBM ODM - How Iterate over column rows (like in a given example)

Tags: loops, foreach, odm, websphere

How in IBM ODM to iterate through each row of decision table column and insert each value of row into method for calculations and finally check which values returned by method is the smallest.

For example:

[image]

```
1. Step
```

For every row of column Bn where A = A1 do:

```
SomeMethod.calculate(B1) return C1 = 10;
SomeMethod.calculate(B2) return C2 = 40;
SomeMethod.calculate(B3) return C3 = 5;

2. Step
```

And get minimum of Cn values.
   In my example it is **5**.

Thanks in advance!